# How to add a sidebar menu (like facebook) to phonegap Android project

Tags: android, cordova, sidebar

Im working with android Phonegap project.i want to add a sidebar like facebook in to my app.Is there any working codes or tutorials under this subject?

Comment: 1) http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/docs/examples/panels/panel-styling.html 2)http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good solution for the sidebar. Use [Intel XDK](http://xdk-software.intel.com/). It will give you drag and drop sidebar to your app. Very simple.